# codeigniter message: Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$Deskripsi

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$Deskripsi
>
> Filename: views/nrc01.php
>
> Line Number: 70

this my controller:

```
function nrc01()
    {
            $data['nrc01Records'] = $this->user_model->getnrc01();

            $process = 'Neraca';
            $processFunction = 'Manager/cr001a';
            $this->logrecord($process,$processFunction);

            $this->global['pageTitle'] = 'Neraca';

            $this->loadViews("nrc01", $this->global, $data, NULL);
    }
```

this my model:

```
function getnrc01()
    {
        $this->dbsqlsrv = $this->load->database('dbsqlsrv', TRUE);
        $this->dbsqlsrv->select('a.posLaporanPosisiKeuangan',
                                'b.Deskripsi',
                                'a.nominalRupiah',
                                'a.nominalValas',
                                'a.nominalValasUSD',
                                'a.nominalValasNonUSD',
                                'a.nominalTotal'
                            );
        $this->dbsqlsrv->from('nrc01.neraca as a');
        $this->dbsqlsrv->join('dbo.RefAsetNeracaKantorAll as b','a.posLaporanPosisiKeuangan = b.sandi','left');
        $where = "idPelapor='137001000' AND periodeLaporan='M' AND periodeData='2019-09-30'";
        $this->dbsqlsrv->where($where);
        $this->dbsqlsrv->order_by('b.id DESC');
        $query = $this->dbsqlsrv->get();
        $result = $query->result();
        return $result;
    }
```

this my view:

```
<tbody>
                    <?php
                      if(!empty($nrc01Records))
                      {
                          foreach($nrc01Records as $record)
                          {
                    ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $record->posLaporanPosisiKeuangan ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $record->Deskripsi ?></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="text-center">
                                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" title="Edit">
                                            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger deleteUser" href="#" data-userid="" title="Hapus">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php
                          }
                      }
                      ?>
                  </tbody>
```

But, contractType won't be printed in page even if it is already has a value. I can't figure out the problem. Any help?
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the error you get, it just means that the field Deskripsi has a null value for at least one of the results of your SQL query in getnrc01() (but I guess that this is expected as your query has a LEFT JOIN clause). But it isn't a critical error, the line `<td><?php echo $record->Deskripsi ?></td>` will just display `<td></td>` in this case.

About the other problem, there isn't any "contractType" mentioned in the code you posted. You might have forgotten to post one part?